# mysql select where keyword appears query

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to create an sql query, to search for multiple keywords in one column (called biography) from the table called (books)

> table = books
>   column = biography

what i have tried :

Works (but only brings back results with only the word gamer):

```
SELECT * FROM books
WHERE biography IN ('gamer');
```

Doesn’t work at all:

```
SELECT * FROM books
WHERE biography IN ('gamer%’);
```

Im trying to look for ANY results including the word gamer

my second question is how to search for multiple keywords at the same time.

Comment: `LIKE '%gamer%'`.  IN is for passing a list.

Comment: i got this error:



Error
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.

ERROR: Unclosed quote @ 42
STR: '
SQL: SELECT * FROM books
WHERE biography LIKE ('gamer%’);

SQL query: Documentation

SELECT * FROM books WHERE biography LIKE ('gamer%’);

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''gamer%â€™)' at line 2

Comment: Sorry, don't include the parens, I edited my comment.

Comment: yes use like '% gamer% 'syntax for this as suggested by others as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use like

With % you use wildcards telling SQL that you want everything biography containing gamer. If you have % in front it means you can have characters before gamer, if after, characters after, and in your case, characters before and after. hope it helps

```
SELECT * FROM books
WHERE biography like '%gamer%';
```

Comment: You could expand your answer by explaining wat the `%` means to OP.

Comment: Sure Stuart... Will adjust my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this and use `OR` to search using multiple keywords

```
SELECT * FROM books
WHERE biography like '%gamer%' OR biography like '%anotherkey%'
```

Comment: how ever im looking for something more like this 
SELECT * FROM books WHERE biography like '%gamer%' OR biography like '%Zelda%' OR biography like '%Mario%' .   ...... so i can search for multiple keywords, im looking to put in up to 20 keywords,   when i try 3 keywords there are less results than with 2 search keywords